# Good work on the Stack Overflow website in general. Who created all this?

Tags: discussion

Your commenting / points system / badges and everything is really nice. Who is credited for all this? Is there somewhere we can read about the progression of the site itself?

Comment: You should start (as with all topics you're interested in) with Google. That would lead you to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) pretty quickly, which is a good starting point.

Comment: Click on your profile.  Note the number in the URL, yours is 5412082.  Change the number.  Users 1, 2 and 3 created the site

Comment: Listen to all the [podcasts](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/tags/podcasts/)

Comment: Please don't add meta noise to your question. Up vote or accept the answers that you like

Comment: It's posted in "meta"

Answer (score 7):

You can check out the about page? https://stackexchange.com/about and come back with any specific questions.